# Yet another issue with stride

Tags: c#, bitmap, stride

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride?view=netframework-4.8) stride for bitmap creating from a byteArray needs to be:

> The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line), rounded up to a four-byte boundary. If the stride is positive, the bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is bottom-up.

I have a byteArray for an image of 640 x 512 pixels. The byte array is created from an arraybuffer that is coming in from a live camera. I am creating the image for the first time. The image format is PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb so one byte per Red, Green and Blue for a total of three bytes per pixel. That makes one line of the image 640 * 3 bytes = 1,920 bytes. Checking to see if this is divisible by four I get 1,920/4 = 480.

When I use a stride of 640 * 3 = 1,920 I get a bad result (a garbled image). What am I doing wrong?

I have verified that my byteArray has the right number of elements and looks correct. My code looks like this:

```
int stride = 1920;
using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(640, 512, stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr)))
{
    return (Bitmap)image.Clone();
}
```

**EDIT**
It is sounding like stride at 1920 is correct and you all are confirming that I understand how stride works. My guess at this point is that my pixel layout (ARGB VS RGB or something like that) is not correct.

This is how the image should look (using a free GenIcam viewer:
[image]

How the "garbled" image looks:
[image]

Comment: You don't *suppose* what the Bitmap Stride is. You extract it from the `BitmapData` object you get from `Bitmap.LockBits`. e.g., `BitmapData data = [Bitmap].LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, [Bitmap].Width, [Bitmap].Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);` (yes, `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`), then the Bitmap byte array is `byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[data.Stride * data.Height];`.

Comment: If you want to be sure about the results, copy the Image to a new Bitmap, using `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`.

Comment: Stride, is the length of the scanline, padded to the next multiple of four bytes. For width=300 it is stride=300, for width=301 it is stride=304..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!

Understanding how stride works was the key. Since I had the correct stride I started looking elsewhere. What happened was I was passing an array with the wrong value to make the bitmap. The values should have values for temperature:

```
23.5, 25.2, 29.8 ...
```

The values actually getting passed were in the thousands range ...
    7501, 7568, 7592 ...

**Garbage in, garbage out...**

Rambling thoughts:
I need to learn how to set up unit tests when doing things like this. Units test are easy when you are testing something like a method to calculate the circumference of a circle. I guess I need to figure out a way to set up a raw data file that simulates the raw data from the camera and run it through all the conversions to get to an image.

Thank you for all your help.